# OR WHERE in zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework

How can I write query like this In Zend Framework and fetch all the rows

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE user_id = $part_mail
OR user_id ='$id3';
```

I used to try this :

```
    $select = $tigaseModel->fetchAll($tigaseModel
                                        ->select()
                                        ->where('user_id = ?', $part_mail )
                                        -> orwhere('user_id = ?', $id3 ));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following ways should help you.

**Solution 1**:

```
where( "user_id = '$part_mail' OR user_id = '$id3'" );
```

**Solution 2**:

```
$list = array( $part_mail, $id3 );
...
where( 'user_id in ( ? )', $list );
```

**Solution 3**:

```
$list = array( $part_mail, $id3 );
...
where( array( 'user_id' => $list ) );
```

**Refer to Documentation**:
[Example #17 Example of an array parameter in the where() method](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html)
-You can pass an array as the second parameter to the where() method when using the SQL IN operator.

Answer (score 0):

orwhere available in Zend Framework 1. But there is a space in your code before orwhere(). Check the code below:

```
$select = $tigaseModel->fetchAll($tigaseModel
                                    ->select()
                                    ->where('user_id = ?', $part_mail )
                                    ->orwhere('user_id = ?', $id3 ));
```